# Defining class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Typically when writing a model in Rails you use a DSL to setup various aspects of derived objects, for example:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  validates_presence_of :category
end
```

In this case, "has_one" and "validates_presence_of" create associations and validation call backs on models instantiated from Question.

I want to add a new method called "parent" to be used when defining a class:

```
class Question
  attr_accessor :category

  parent :category
end

q = Question.new
q.category = 'a category'
puts q.parent
-> 'a category'
```

So when objects are instantiated from class, they should have the method "parent" defined.

How do I do this?  My first thought was to use a module, but this isn't an instance method, or a class method.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want `parent` to do. As you've described it, there is both a class method (called as `parent :category` and and instance method (`q.parent`). Do you just need `q.parent` to alias `q.category`?

Comment: In this case yes, def parent; category; end; .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
module QuestionParent
  module ClassMethods
    def inherited(descendant)
      descendant.instance_variable_set(:@parent, parent.dup)
      super
    end

    def parent(args=nil)
      @parent ||= args
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def parent
      self.send self.class.parent.to_sym
    end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend         ClassMethods
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end
end

class Question
  include QuestionParent

  attr_accessor :category

  parent :category
end
```

Which produces:

```
q = Question.new
q.category = 'a category'
puts q.parent

a category
```

What this does is add a class method `parent` that will define the class variable `@parent`, when an instance calls the `parent` in the `InstanceMethod` the `@parent` symbol (here is `category`) is called.

Comment: +1. This is a common ruby idiom that allows `include` to add both class and instance methods.

Comment: Thanks @heelhook , I get NameError: uninitialized class variable @@parent in QuestionParent::InstanceMethods executing your sample code ... wondering where this is should be defined?

Comment: @juwiley I just realized I had tested with ```q.category``` instead of ```q.parent```. Sorry about that, I have redited the code in the answer.

Comment: I also ran across https://practicingruby.com/articles/shared/iptocucwujtj which has a more in-depth explanation of similar techniques